# Passing values to a dict whilst in a for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, dictionary

So, I have a folder which has subfolders, each containing 40 images.

I am iterating over every image within each subfolder using the following code:

```
for (dirname, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk('C:\.....')
    for filename in filenames:
```

The images are titled as follows:

**1st folder:** IM-0239-0001.dcm,
IM-0239-0002.dcm,
IM-0239-0003.dcm...........IM-0239-0040.dcm

**2nd folder** IM-0248-0001.dcm,
IM-0248-0002.dcm,
IM-0248-0003.dcm.....IM-0248-0040.dcm

What I want to do is perform an operation on each of the 40 images in a sub-folder, get the average of these and then export this value along with the sub-folder identifier e.g "0239" to a dictionary outside of the for loop.

I am having trouble with passing the average value BEFORE moving onto the next sub-folder. My ideal solution, if say 4 sub-folders exists, passes 4 sub-folder UIs and their corresponding average value to a dictionary.

I have tried using .split based function (below) combined with an if statement inside the above loop to compare parts[1] in order to detect a sub-folder ending:

```
parts = image_name.split('-')
return '-'.join((parts[1], parts[0], parts[2]))
```

but I looking for a more pythonic, chic and faster way of doing this.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "export this value". If you have problems with certain code, it makes no sense to post your code _except_ for the actual code that doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, English is terribl. Is this any better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have one image directory with one level of subdirectories containing images. You want to process the images grouped by the containing subdirectory.

You can first read in the structure:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import os

tobeprocessed = {}
for curdir, subdirs, files in os.walk ('/home/lorenzo/stackoverflow/images'):
    if not files: continue
    tobeprocessed [curdir] = files

print (tobeprocessed)
```

Now you have a dictionary whose keys are the folders and whose values are the containing files, which you can process as you see fit.

Comment: This is why I love stack over flow, something much better and more dynamic than what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Ha ha, you get +1 because you were able to understand the question ;) Congrats!

Comment: Sorry guys, I am badly writing the questions!